# Uninitialized Constant modelname with Mongoid on Rails 3.1

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3.1, mongoid

I just setup my first Rails 3.1 app with mongoid :

```
$ bundle install
[...]
Using bson_ext (1.5.1)
Using mongoid (2.2.4)
```

I created my first model :

```
class Chapter
  include Mongoid::Document
  field :name
end
```

When I run irb, I get this :

```
$ irb
1.8.7 :001 > Chapter.new
NameError: uninitialized constant Chapter
from (irb):1
```

What am I missing ?

Answer (score 1):

You must use `rails c` instead of `irb` to load the environment and only then you'll be able to use model methods.